# Non-Jersey JAX-RS Custom Exception with Status Code

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I'm using Apache Wink with JAX-RS, and I'm working on throwing custom exceptions for error handling. I was able to get something working far enough to send back a custom JSON message with a status code, but I'd like the ability to use this custom Exception for more than just one type of Response (in this case, `Status.BAD_REQUEST`). How can I inject a status code into my exception so that I can throw more than one type of status with the custom error message?

**JAX-RS Resource**

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response memberRegistration(
        JSONObject json,
        @HeaderParam("Client-ID") String clientId,
        @HeaderParam("Client-Secret") String clientSecret) throws WebApplicationException, Exception {

        // Authenticate the user using the credentials provided
        appAuth.checkClientId(clientId, clientSecret);
        if (!"new".equals(json.get("type_of_membership"))) {
            throw new WebApplicationException("Type of membership (new) is not correct for this route.");
        }
        return Response.ok(json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();

}
```

**Custom Exception**

```
public class WebApplicationException extends Exception implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public WebApplicationException() {
        super();
    }
    public WebApplicationException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
    public WebApplicationException(String msg, Exception e)  {
        super(msg, e);
    }
}
```

**Custom Exception Handler/ExceptionMapper implementation**

```
@Provider
public class WebApplicationExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<WebApplicationException> 
{
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(WebApplicationException exception) 
    {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("message", exception.getMessage());
        return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(json.toString()).build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I got your question, but I could suggest that adding an instance variable to your custom exception to hold the status code that you want, you can do that as follow:

```
public class WebApplicationException extends Exception implements Serializable
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Response.Status status = Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST;

public WebApplicationException() {
    super();
}
public WebApplicationException(String msg) {
    super(msg);
}
public WebApplicationException(String msg, Exception e)  {
    super(msg, e);
}

public WebApplicationException(String msg, Response.Status status) {
    super(msg);
    this.status = status;
}
public WebApplicationException(String msg, Exception e, Response.Status status)  {
    super(msg, e);
    this.status = status;
}

public Response.Status getStatus() {
     return status;
}
}
```

then you can modify the return statement in "WebApplicationExceptionHandler" as

```
return Response.status(exception.getStatus()).entity(json.toString()).build();
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, the getStatus() both in the Exception, and the ExceptionMapper was what I was looking for, but unable to do.